# Trouble selecting checkbox on website

Tags: ajax, vba, excel

after a couple of days of trying, and failing, i need some help please.
I'm trying to select a check box on an website, but it doesn't seems to work as I want to.

the check box is part of a row in a table, together with some other data. The idea is that I log in on the site (http://www.apf.asn.au), go to the table, find the numbers I need from my excel sheet, and select the box that is in the row the number is found.

the log in and navigate to table part is working ok, but I can't find the proper way to select the box.

code from the site:

```
<div class="table">
  <div>
    <table class="table APFGrid StudentsSearch"
           id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMainNoAjax_gvJumpRecordsList"
           style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0"
      <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr> 'Header
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span class="clsSelect">
              <input
       name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMainNoAjax$gvJumpRecordsList$ctl02$chkSelect"
       id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMainNoAjax_gvJumpRecordsList_ctl02_chkSelect"
       onclick="javascript:ToggleCheckBoxSelection;" type="checkbox"></input>
            </span>
          </td> 'Box need to check
          <td class="Name">...</td>
          <td class="Name">...</td>
          <td class="DateBirth">...</td>
          <td class="APFNum">...</td> 'Number I'm looking for
          <td class="JumpType">...</td>
          <td class="DateBooked">...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td class="Name">...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>...</tr>
        Etc.
```

I use this code:

```
'Get APF Number from Pipe
xNr = "20819334"

'Search Number online
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
For Each Row In APFtable
    If i = 0 Then
        Set Member = Row.getElementsByTagName("th")
    Else
        Set Member = Row.getElementsByTagName("td")
    End If
    i = i + 1

    On Error Resume Next
    If xNr = Member(4).innerText Then

        'Check the corresponding checkbox 

        Exit For
    End If
Next Row
```

to compare the number, in my example: xNr, to the numbers in the table. But I can't figure out how to check the box.

I tried this code:

```
Name = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMainNoAjax$gvJumpRecordsList$ct" & 100 + i & "$chkSelect"
Set Check = IE.Document.GetElementsByName(Name)
If Not Check Is Nothing Then
    Check(0).Click
End If
```

end all the other ways I could find in other forums to get it to work, although this came closest to working. which means that it worked when I hard-coded the name in the variable with out the "calculating position" part.

can someone advice me on my problem?
Much appreciated

Comment: `Member(4).parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click` Should do it if there's only one input element on the row you're checking.

Comment: +1, execly what I was looking for

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer - if you could accept it that will help people with similar questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Member(4).parentElement.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click
```

Should do it if the checkbox is the first input element on that row.